# How the enable USB ports on a touch only PC after they were disabled by mistake

Tags: usb, display, bios, touchscreen

By mistake I have disabled the USB ports on my ZedNote i-Life.

Nothing is working except the touch screen and volume buttons, so I can’t log in again to the BIOS settings to enable it.

Is there any way to reset the BIOS settings from Windows or clear the settings I have made? I can't find the CMOS battery or something like that on the motherboard.

Comment: yes i wanted to install ubuntu then i couldn't boot from usb

Comment: Read your pad/laptop/mainboard manual. Modern MBs have a jumper for clearing BIOS. And most also have an exchangable CMOS battery.

Comment: nothing in manual

Comment: still not solved until now